# How do i get rid of the term none here and what is it?

Tags: python, nonetype

I've created a basic addition statement, i am aware that input is being read as a string but my code prints out "none" before taking an input (see below).  How do i take integer as an input??

```
# code example
print("This is a calculator")
a = input(print("Enter the first number"))
b = input(print("Enter the second number"))
print("sum =", a + b)
```

This outputs:

```
This is a calculator
Enter the first number
None5
Enter the second number
None6
sum = 56
```

Comment: Take the `print()` out of your `input` statements.

Comment: Please post code as text and not an image of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `print()` in the first two lines:

```
a = input("Enter the first number")
b = input("Enter the second number")
```

instead of:

```
a = input(print("Enter the first number"))
b = input(print("Enter the second number"))
```

`None` is the return of the `print()` function so since `input()` prints what you input to it you are printing the returned `None` value. Then the print statement will still print the prompt. However you want to let `input()` print the prompt as described above.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` prints the prompt for you. You just have to enter `a = input("Enter the first number")`